# Facebook login data loss after reopening app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have added Facebook Login code inside fragment. Everything works fine,i can login into my app but when i change fragment or reopen app after login every data are gone i.e email,name,birthday.it doesn't shows any data.so, what should i do to save those data.

**code**

```
    public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment{
    ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    RelativeLayout fbbg;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    LoginButton btnLogin;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    CircleImageView profilePicture;
    TextView email;
    TextView gender;
    TextView facebookName;
    TextView birthday;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    public static final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("public_profile");
    add("email");
    add("user_photos");
    add("user_birthday");
}};

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstantState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    btnLogin = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.view);

    email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.un2);

    facebookName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username);

    birthday = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bd2);

    gender = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gnd2);

    profilePicture = (CircleImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl);

    fbbg = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    btnLogin.setReadPermissions(mPermissions);
    btnLogin.setFragment(this);
    btnLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.d("JSON", ""+response.getJSONObject().toString());
                            try {
                                fbbg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                email.setText(object.getString("email"));
                                gender.setText(object.getString("gender"));
                                facebookName.setText(object.getString("name"));
                                birthday.setText(object.getString("birthday"));
                                Glide.with(getActivity())
                                        .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + object.getString("id") + "/picture?type=large")
                                        .into(profilePicture);
                                pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                editor.putString("name", String.valueOf(facebookName));
                                editor.putString("email", String.valueOf(email));
                                editor.putString("gender", String.valueOf(gender));
                                editor.putString("birthday", String.valueOf(birthday));
                                editor.commit();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                                                           AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                    if (currentAccessToken == null) {
                        facebookName.setText("");
                        email.setText("");
                        gender.setText("");
                        birthday.setText("");
                        profilePicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
                    }
                }
            };
            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cancled to Login Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error to Login Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); return view;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    pref.getString("name", "asdfgh");
    pref.getString("email", "qwerty");
    pref.getString("gender", "zxcvb");
    pref.getString("birthday", "kdhfaj");
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onResume();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

[After login pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdi3G.png)
[After reopening app pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48vTB.png)

Comment: add all value in local database ya shared preference

Comment: Why don't you save your FB login data in "SharedPreference"

Comment: i tried with SharedPreference but it didn't work

Comment: show us what have you tried...

Comment: i have changed my code @A.R.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity());
}
```

No need to do this.

whenever you are resuming the fragment then that time it is creating the fresh instance of your facebook profile thats why data loss is happening.

on resume just reload fragment dont create new instace.

whenever you get data from facebook api immediately store it to shared preferences. after that you can fetch that data whenever you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
public UpdateFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_updates, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // define your xml resources here

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    loadUpdates();
}

private void loadUpdates() {

        // api call
}
```

}

Try to embed your code into this fragment lifecycle. it will surely work.

There is no need to add onResume()

just do your stuff in loadUpdates(); method.

Comment: is there any need of SharedPreference now? @Dnyanesh

Comment: SharedPreferences are used to store persistant data. if everytime user coming with login then there is no need of shared pref.

Comment: whant should i add inside private void loadUpdates() {

        // api call
} @Dnyanesh

Comment: facebook api call code add inside loadUpdates() method

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code wrt SharedPreference.
You can try that.

```
        pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GIVE SOME name TO FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("name", object.getString("name"));
        editor.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
        editor.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
        editor.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
        editor.apply();
```

Replace above code with your existing code, once you successfully get user profile information from FB

Comment: Have you tried getting values from preferences in some other class with same file name and key name,just for testing purpose after setting the preference in above mentioned class.

Comment: yeah. previously it was an activity but also i was getting same problem @A.R

Comment: It does not matter whether its an activity or fragment. If you are able get required info in onCompleted() then your values should saved in preferences. Secondly make sure there is not an exception as you are using try catch block.

Comment: nope i wasnt getting my datas and i m not getting any exception

Comment: If you are not getting any data in onCompleted(), then how you can save the relevant data in Preferences. Your question is that you are not been able to persist your data which you are getting from FB. Here, you are saying you are not getting any information of user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your `SharedPreferences` was initialized with an `Activity`. To avoid your data is lost when the `Activity` destroyed, you should use `ApplicationContext()`.
I made a separated class with `SharedPreference` like this:

```
public class SessionManager {

// Shared Preferences reference
public SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor reference for Shared preferences
private Editor editor;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context context;
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
public static final String PREFER_NAME = "login";
public static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return pref.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, "");
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_NAME, userName);
    editor.commit();
}
```

In your `Fragment`, initializing `SharedPreferences` with:

```
sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity.getApplicationContext());
```

saving your data:

```
session.setUserName(object.getString("name"));
```

Retrieving data at later times by called:

```
String userName = session.getUserName();
```